# Unable to get an addrole command working in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i've encountered an issue where I can't seem to get my **addrole** command to work. I've searched through every video and article and have spent hours to try and figure out why my code isn't working.

I want it so whenever a admin calls the **,addrole** command, the user they mentioned gets that role.
(example: ,addrole @{rolename} {@user}).

Here is 2 sections of the code which I think may be the issue.

Here is the imports and some other things.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from discord import Intents
import os
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.utils import get
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=",", intents=intents)
```

Here is the command.

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addrole(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} has successfully received the role {role.mention}.")
```

I've tried changing so many things but whenever I run it and call the command nothing happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is not responding as it is missing `client.command()` which actually calls the command

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addrole(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} has successfully received the role {role.mention}.")
```

It may also be better if your allow the role to have multiple arguments, which means you can add a role to a user with spaces, for example, **This role** instead of **Thisrole**, this can be added by adding * which creates an multiple string argument. You would then need to pass it as the last argument.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member=None, *, role: discord.Role):

    if user == None:
        await ctx.send('Please format like ,addrole @member role')
        return
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} has successfully received the role {role.mention}.")
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. Turns out I did have the client.command() but didn't copy and paste it into the question. Unfortunetly I still get the same result. @Cohen

Comment: Could you update your question to exactly the same code and parts where it could have the issue?

Comment: I seem to have fixed the issue. I forgot to add ```await client.process_commands(message)``` at the end of my on_message(). @Cohen